# how to set width of template field in grid view in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have template field in grid view i want to reduce width to 20 px , how to reduce or set width of a template field in gridview?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Day Id">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LblDayId" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DayId") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblEditDayId" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DayId") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate >
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddDayId" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ItemStyle` and `HeaderStyle` and `FooterStyle` to set `Width`

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Day Id">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LblDayId" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DayId") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle Width="20px" />
<HeaderStyle  Width="20px" />
 <FooterStyle Width="20px" />                                                   
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblEditDayId" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DayId") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: but for footer ?? its not decreasing the size due to footer is ther. any idea ???@ganesh

Comment: ya worked , but have to add width = 20 px for text box in footer...@ganesh

Comment: @krishnamohan set  width of textbox to 20px