# Resize sql table in datagridview windows form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I show SQL table size to be of my own choice in Grid View Windows form c#?

I have tried `datagridview.AutoResizeColumns()` but it doesn't work.

Comment: what do you mean by _table size_? the number of records? the disk space the table takes? the width of the columns in the grid?....

Comment: @Gooda  well you can use templates to customize the  width and styles of tables   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32879811/how-to-set-width-of-template-field-in-grid-view-in-asp-net

Comment: @GiladGreen actually i want to show the results onto full screen view on my Windows Form.... but neither MaximizeBox = false; nor WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized; is working when i fetch data from SQL in my winform